# Can WebMatrix Compile My Asp.net MVC Project ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmatrix

Mostly I use Visual studio to write mock-up and the back-end code. I want to try  WebMatrix but I want to know the following :
Can WebMatrix compile the code I wrote in visual studio and Restart the project.

How do other programmers (if any) use WebMatrix with ASP.NET MVC. Any idea how to use WebMatrix and Visual Studio at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as MVC applications are concerned, WebMatrix is little more than a text editor. WebMatrix is designed to work primarily with the Web Pages development model, which is based on the Web Site (folder-based projects) approach as opposed to the Web Application approach (pre-compilation). MVC is therefore not supported.